# how to make frontend user login and admin login in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have requirement of user login in frontend and also i need to make admin panel in laravel, i have create custom user table for frontend user because its have multiple other fields, in this case if i use laravel php artisan make:auth then it will create laravel login that i can redirect to different route(different admin folder in views) but if i use laravel default login and add frontend user custom fields in db table then how can i use this direction? My main question is, i need to use laravel make:auth db table for front end user and administrator user with different role or i need to make two different tables for both admin and frontuser login?

Comment: Hi Ketan. There are a tons of tutorials about this. Give a try and come back if you have any real programming question.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use the package below to do this.
The following package contains the Role&Permission - registration and login.](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

If your problem is not resolved, I can help you more.